# Spring-Test-Framework for 1.6 project

Tags: java, spring, testing, controller

i've a project with jdk1.6.0_45.
Now i want to test my spring-controller. 
I get this exception:

> javax/servlet/ServletException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>   I suppose, that some dependencies were compiled with 1.7

And when i execute my test with jre1.7, it works, but i get some other error.
I guess, i have to execute tests with a same jre-version like a project, which i want to test.

**Whole dependencies and source-code you can find here:**

> https://www.luckyryan.com/2013/08/24/unit-test-controllers-spring-mvc-test/

I can't execute this with jdk1.6.0_45.